# What's wrong with that line? (js)

Tags: javascript, php, html

Can someone tell me the problem with this line?

```
   <td align="center"><a  style="font-weight:normal;" href="javascript:deleteAssignment(<?php echo $id; ?>,<?php echo "'".$code."'"; ?>,<?php echo $hid; ?>);" >Delete</a></td>
```

the js function :

```
function deleteAssignment(id,code,hid)
{
    if (confirm('delete this tuple?')) {
        window.location.href = 'assign/process.php?action=delete&id=' + id +'&code='+code+'&hid='+hid;
    }
}
```

When i click on the link nothing happens and i made sure the two files are connected and also the parameters are well echoed .

Comment: There's nothing 'wrong' with the line from a syntax point-of-view. What makes you think there is something wrong? Is it not giving you the output you expect? In that case, you'll need to tell you what output it is **currently** giving you, along with what output you **expect** it to give you. You'll probably also need to state what your PHP variables are.

Comment: are $is, $code and $hid all numeric? if not, you may have a problem there - check the source code of the page **in the browser** to see what the href looks like

Comment: thanks for answering , no the $code is  string but when i checked on the navigator it looks pretty accurate

Comment: "pretty accurate" ... but wrong, if $code is a string ... show **exactly** what the browser gets ... if it's something like `href="javascript:deleteAssignment(123, some string, some other string);"` then that is invalid

Comment: `nothing happens` - how about in the browsers developer tools console? does "something" happen there?

Comment: href="javascript:deleteAssignment(8,'9CN3Y',26);" 
here's what the source code in the browsers gives me

Answer (score 0):

> I think mistake in `$code` or `$hid` variable may it is string so problem with quote.
>
> `href` is not a event function you need to add `onclick` event.

Try below code may it'll help to you,

```
<?php
    $id    = 10;
    $code  = 'Hello World !';
    $hid   = 123;
?>

<td align="center">
    <a style="font-weight:normal;" href="#" onclick="deleteAssignment('<?php echo $id; ?>','<?php echo $code; ?>','<?php echo $hid; ?>');">Delete</a>
</td>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteAssignment(id,code,hid)
    {
        if (confirm('Supprimer ce tuple?')) {
            console.log('assign/process.php?action=delete?id='+id+'&code='+code+'&hid='+hid);
            window.location.href = 'assign/process.php?action=delete&id=' + id +'&code='+code+'&hid='+hid;
        }
    }

</script>
```

Thank you !